# High Egress using Spark-Kafka Adapter on EventHub

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-eventhub

We have an EventHub Namespace with 2 EventHubs, 32 partitions and 20 Throughput Units. One of the Eventhubs is dormant with very little throughput and the other has much higher throughput, accounting for > 90% of outgoing messages. Each Throughput Unit (TU) permits the lower (?) of 2MB or 4096 messages per second, so we should be able to pull through 2 x 20 x 60 MB (2.4GB) or 4,096 x 20 x 60 (4,915,200) messages per minute.

The maximum size of an event that we are producing is ~40kb. We are consuming using a Spark Structured Stream with microbatch sizes of 32 offsets (1.28 MB) triggering roughly every 1.5 seconds - so an estimated egress rate of 51.2 MB per minute (~2.1% of maximum permitted egress).

We are observing that the sum of outgoing messages in bytes per minute is much higher than expected, and as a result we are being throttled. We have confirmed the size of each microbatch to be well below what is being reported. Any ideas as to what might be causing this misalignment? Another point to note is that we are using the [Spark-Kafka adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-spark-tutorial) instead of Microsoft's [Spark Eventhub Connector](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark)

Spark UI
[image: Spark UI]

Eventhub Metrics (1 minute time-granularity)
[image: Eventhub Metrics]

---

```
spark
  .readStream 
  .format("kafka") 
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xxxxx") 
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") 
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") 
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL) 
  .option("subscribe", "xxxxx") 
  .option("sasl.mechanisms", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") 
  .option("includeHeaders", true)
  .option("truncate", false)
  .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 32)
  .load
  .writeStream
  .format("noop")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "xxxxx")
  .trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow)
  .start
```

Comment: Can you confirm if you are writing to a single output stream or multiple? I've had experience that this kind of issue occurs when opening up multiple output streams. Maybe a snippet of code which reads the input stream and writes to output stream/s would help.

Comment: we're using the "noop" output format, so the data just gets flushed from memory once its been consumed / transformed.

Comment: What do you mean consumed? Can you share the code of the consumption/transformation and this flushing?

Comment: @AnupamChand I mean read from the eventhub.

Comment: By the way we've solved the problem and I'll type up the outcome later today - we swapped out the spark-kafka adapter for the spark eventhub connector and the throughput being reported in eventhub metrics made much more sense. I suspect there's an implementation defect in the spark-kafka adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we replaced the [Spark-Kafka](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-spark-tutorial) adapter with the [Spark Eventhub Connector](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark) and the metrics being reported were far more closely aligned to expectations given the configuration of the stream. We ran 3 tests

- 1,000 offsets per trigger (1 second trigger)

  - resulting in ~140MB of egress per minute.
  - No Throttling
- 10,000 offsets per trigger  (1 second trigger)

  - resulting in ~1.5GB of egress per minute.
  - No Throttling
- 15,000 offsets per trigger (1 second trigger)

  - resulting in ~2GB of egress per minute.
  - Some (minimal) Throttling

Eventhub metrics below, note that the peaks in the graph can be explained by inconsistencies in the message sizes - users with more consistent message sizes should see a flatter graph.

[image: Eventhub Metrics]

---

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

val eventHubsConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
  .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromStartOfStream)
  .setMaxEventsPerTrigger(15000)
  .setConsumerGroup("testytest")
  .setReceiverTimeout(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(30))
  .setOperationTimeout(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(30))

spark
  .readStream
  .format("eventhubs")
  .options(eventHubsConf.toMap)
  .load
  .writeStream
  .format("noop")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 seconds"))
  .option("checkpointLocation", "xxxxx")
  .start
```